# MySQL, move data from rows to columns with Images pictures

Tags: mysql

table1

```
id  id_customer name_photo1   photo_1      name_photo2  photo_2 
1.  1           pic.png       *sdhsadj     jsjs.png     *ssksksks
2.  2           pic2.png      *sadjsad     sdds.png     *ssddsdsdw
```

To table2

```
id.  id_customer  namefoto    picture
1.   1            pic.png     *sdhsadj 
2    1            jsjs.png    *ssksksks
3.   2            pic2.png    *sadjsad 
4.   2            sdds.png    *ssddsdsdw
```

As I can move the data with a query from the table to the table2, the column photo_1 and photo_2 is longblob.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does this need to be a purely mysql solution?

Comment: Also - please see this: [why should I provide an mcve for a simple SQL problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "MySQL, move data from columns to rows with Images pictures" ? You need to "unpivot" with `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "unpivot" to convert columns into records. 
You can do it in one query with `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` in combination with `UNION ALL`

```
INSERT INTO 
 table2
(
    table2.id_customer 
  , table2.namefoto
  , table2.picture
)
SELECT 
   records.id_customer 
 , records.namefoto
 , records.picture
FROM (
  SELECT 
     table1.id_customer AS id_customer 
   , table1.name_photo1 AS namefoto
   , table1.photo_1 AS picture  
  FROM 
   table1

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 
     table1.id_customer AS id_customer 
   , table1.name_photo2 AS namefoto
   , table1.photo_2 AS picture  
  FROM 
   table1
) AS records
ORDER BY
  records.customer_id ASC
```

Comment: 1054 - Unknown column 'table2.name_photo1' in 'field list', Time: 0.000000s

Comment: I think it must be `table1` instead of `table2` in SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO
  table2(id_customer, namefoto, picture)
SELECT
  id_customer,
  name_photo1,
  photo_1
FROM
  table1;
```

```
INSERT INTO
  table2(id_customer, namefoto, picture)
SELECT
  id_customer,
  name_photo2,
  photo_2
FROM
  table1;
```